# How can I get nUnit to be configured under the SYSTEM account so that Jenkins/MSBuild can use it?

Tags: msbuild, nunit, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins with MSBuild on a Windows XP machine and am attempting to get my nUnit tests to build. Currently I get the following error :

```
warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "nunit.framework, Version=2.6.0.12051, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
```

If I open up a command prompt and run MSBuild as my own user account, everything works.
I know that Jenkins uses the SYSTEM account rather than my account, so to mimic this I've used `PSTools\PsExec.exe -i -s cmd.exe` and ran MSBuild from that and by doing that I can reproduce the error which leads me to believe its a configuration issue with nUnit.

So, how can I configure nUnit so that it works from the SYSTEM account?
I'd rather not install it into the GAC if I can get away with it, and I'm also keen to continue using the SYSTEM account for Jenkins

Thanks!

Comment: Update: To get this to work in the short term I have deployed it to the GAC and that does work. But I'd love to know how else to do it

Comment: Why not run Jenkins from an account with build privileges? If the node you're building on is a Jenkins slave, there's an option in the node configuration to set the user to run as.

Comment: I could do that I guess. Thanks